# Continuity of a function over the open interval

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{n}{2}}$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.
From the definition of textbook , I tried to prove it's continuous at every point over $(0, \infty)$.But, how can I do that?

Could someone help me to figure out it?I am really appreciated it!

Comment: Are $x$ and $\sqrt{x}$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$? Is the product of two continuous functions continuous?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What definitions of continuity have you already studied? Do you have any characterization that would be helpful (for instance, what happens when you compose continuous functions, etc.)?

Comment: Can you post that proof you said you tried?

Comment: This is the definition I have studied: If f  is defined on an open interval, then f is continuous
on (a, b) if and only if limx→cf(x) = f(c) for every a < c < b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PART (1). For $x>0$: When $y\geq x/2$ we have $$|\sqrt y\;-\sqrt x|=\frac {|\sqrt y\;-\sqrt x|\cdot (\sqrt y\;+\sqrt x)}{\sqrt y\;+\sqrt x}=$$ $$\frac {|y-x|}{\sqrt y \;+\sqrt x}\leq \frac {|y-x|}{(3/2)\sqrt x}.$$ So for $x>0$ and $e>0$ let $d=\min \left(\frac {x}{2},\frac { e}{(3/2)\sqrt x}\right).$ Then $$|y-x|<d\implies |\sqrt y\;-\sqrt x|<e.$$

So $\sqrt x$ is continuous at $x.$

PART (2).  If $f$ and $ g$ are continuous at $x$: Given $e>0$ :

Let $r_1>0$ such that $(\;|y-x|<r_1\land y\in dom (f)\;)\implies |f(y)-f(x)|\cdot |g(x)|<e/3.$

Let $r_2>0$ such that $(\;|y-x|<r_2\land y\in dom (g)\;)\implies |g(y)-g(x)|\cdot |f(x)|<e/3.$

Let $r_3>0$ such that $(\;|y-x|<r_3\land y\in dom (f)\;)\implies |f(y)-f(x)|<\min (1,e/3).$

Let $r_4>0$ such that $(\;|y-x)<r_4\land y\in dom (g)\;)\implies |g(y)-g(x)|<\min (1,e/3).$

Now let $r=\min (r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4)$ For $y\in (-r+x,r+x)\cap dom(f)\cap dom (g),$ for brevity let $f(y)=f(x)+a$ and $g(y)=g(x)+b.$

We have $|a|<1$ and $|b|<e/3$  so $|ab|<e/3$. And we have $|ag(x)|<e/3$ and $|bf(x)|<e/3.$

So, finally,  we have  $$|f(y)g(y)-f(x)g(x)|=$$ $$=|(f(x)+a)(g(x)+b)-f(x)g(x)|=$$ $$=|ag(x)+bf(x)+ab|\leq$$ $$\leq |ag(x)|+|bf(x)|+|ab|<$$ $$<e/3+e/3+e/3=e.$$

So the product $fg$ is continuous at $x.$

PART (3). If $f_1,..,f_n$ are continuous   then $\prod_{j=1}^n f_j$ is continuous .

Proof (by induction on  $n$): The case $n=1$ is trivial. The case $n=2$ is Part (2). Suppose it is true for $n_0\geq 2$. Let $f=\prod_{j=1}^{n_0}f_j$ and $g=f_{n+1}.$ Then $f,g$ are continuous, so $\prod_{j=1}^{n_0+1}f_j=fg$ is continuous.

PART (4). Application.. For $n\in \mathbb n$ and $x>0$: For $1\leq j\leq n$ let $f_j(x)=\sqrt x.$ Then each $f_j$ is continuous by Part (1). And $x^{n/2}=\prod_{j=1}^n f_j(x)$ is continuous by Part (3).

Comment: Thanks! this is to prove the function is uniformly continuous, right?

Comment: No,and  it is not uniformly continuous. It is to prove it is continuous.